# Apex - Base64Decoding to Send Images to AWS3

Tags: apex, visualforce, amazon-s3, amazon

We are having a bit of trouble when it comes to sending an image to AmazonS3 through Apex.

In our JavaScript, within our VisualForce page, we're able to convert an image to Base64 and send it to our Apex Class.  From Apex, we've had success Posting an object to AWS3, but have not had success in it being an image. We were able to send over the encoded Base64 image string to AWS3 and see the full string data in an .XML file was posted into our intended bucket.

I used [this site](https://www.base64decode.org/) to check our data by putting the xml file of it into the ‘Decode files from Base64 format’ section - It was able to decode and give me our image.

We think there's a need to decode the Base64 image string and then send the image to AWS3, but we're running into this error when we click the 'Submit' button on the VF page, in an attempt to send the uploaded image to AWS3...

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
sforce.Xml {faultcode: "soapenv:Client", faultstring: "System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 …1↵Class.May12UploadTest.request: line 8, column 1"}
faultcode: "soapenv:Client"
faultstring: "System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string\n\nClass.AWS.SDK.send: line 73, column 1\nClass.AWS.SDK.call: line 16, column 1\nClass.AWS.S3.PutObject.call: line 1145, column 1\nClass.May12UploadTest.request: line 8, column 1"
__proto__: Object
```

We're working with [this installed package.](https://github.com/bigassforce/aws-sdk)

Here is our Apex Code...

```
global class May12UploadTest {
    @RemoteAction
    webservice static string request(string fileName, string body) {
        AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest request = new AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest();
        request.url = 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/salesforce-simplyhome-images/' + fileName + '.png';
        Blob data = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body);
        request.body = data;
        AWS.S3.PutObjectResponse response = new AWS.S3.PutObject().call(request);
      return response.versionId;  
    }     
}
```

Here is the VF code we're working with...

```
<apex:page standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleForImageUpload}"/>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.839.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js"/>
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newRow = row.insertCell(i);
    newRow.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    newRow.childNodes[0].value = "";
  }
}


function deleteRow(row) {
  var table = document.getElementById("data");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if (rowCount > 1) {
    var rowIndex = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("data").deleteRow(rowIndex);
  }
  else {
    alert("Please specify at least one value.");
  }
}


function getBase64(file, onLoadCallback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() { resolve(reader.result); };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
async function s3upload() {
  var uniqueId,
  element = document.getElementById("uniqueId").value;
  if (element != "") {
      uniqueId = element;
  }
  else {
       alert("Please specify a Unique ID. This has been emailed to you.");
       return;
  }
  var updatedFileName = document.getElementsByClassName("updatedFileName");  
  var files = document.getElementsByClassName("uploadFile");
  function toArray(arr) {
    return [].slice.call(arr);
  }
  var files_arr = toArray(files).filter(v => v.files[0] != null);
  var actual_files = new Array();
  var errors_arr = new Array();
  files_arr.forEach(function callback(file_obj,i){
    actual_files[i] = file_obj.files[0]
  })   
  var updated_file_names_arr = toArray(updatedFileName);
  var image_count = actual_files.length;
  var final_image_index = image_count-1;
  var success_count = 0;
  var error_count = 0;
  var final_message = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i <= final_image_index; i++ ) {
    var file = actual_files[i];
    var fileName = updatedFileName[i].value;
    var promise = getBase64(file);
    promise.then(function(result) {
        
      var resp = sforce.apex.execute("May12UploadTest", "request",{fileName: fileName, body: result.split(",")[1] });
    });
  };
  var total_count = success_count + error_count;
  var uploaded_percent = 100 * total_count / image_count;
  document.getElementById("progress").value = uploaded_percent;
  if (uploaded_percent == 100) {
    var final_message = success_count + " images uploaded successfully. ";
    if (error_count != 0) {
        final_message += "Errors encountered uploading: ";
        final_message += errors_arr;
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(final_message);
    },5);
  };
};
</script>
<br></br><br></br><br></br>
<div id="main">
 <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!May12UploadTest}" name="s3test"/>
 </apex:form>
  <h1>Please Upload Home Images</h1>
  <table id="header" class="data-table data-table-horizontal data-table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Please Enter Unique ID (Emailed to you)</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="uniqueId" value="" placeholder="Enter Unique ID" required="true"/></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="data" class="data-table data-table-horizontal data-table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      
 </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" value="false"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Image of what?" class="updatedFileName"/></td>
 <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>    
  <tr>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="top-buffer" onclick="addRow('data')" />
  </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <div class="pull-center">
<input type="button" class="top-buffer" value="Submit All Images" onclick="s3upload()" />
    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <progress id="progress" max='100' value='0'></progress>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: Is the field `request.body` a Blob or a String? If it is a String, perhaps you should be setting the Base64 text string directly there?

Comment: @KeithC - The body comes in as a string (since we had to encode an image to Base64 to pass it to Apex.  Then, we try to decode that string back into a blob (Blob data = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body);).. From there, we set request.body = data; so we're hoping that will set request.body to a Blob (aka the decoded Base64 image we want to upload)

Comment: It seems that the installed package is calling a request.body.toString() or String.valueOf( request.body ) on your Blob data.  It's easy enough to reproduce the error but I'm not sure what recourse you have.  If you put your encoded string into the body directly I suspect you won't get and error but will end up with a text file on the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be an issue with the utility itself, probably [here](https://github.com/mattandneil/aws-sdk/blob/master/S3.cls#L1253). The utility tries to serialize the `request` which is likely causing the issue. Making a callout yourselves using the named credential directly does work.

```
global PutObjectResponse call(PutObjectRequest request) {
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, this);
    }
    System.Callable sdk = (System.Callable) Type.forName('AWS.SDK').newInstance();
    return (PutObjectResponse) sdk.call(PutObjectRequest.class.getName(), (Map<String, Object>) Json.deserializeUntyped(Json.serialize(request, true)));
}
```

The `SDK` class is not exposed so we don't know how it is working.